# Determine the number of simple graphs with 10 vertices and 15 edges, containing a complete subgraph with 5 vertices .

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Determine the number of simple graphs with 10 vertices and 15 edges,
>   containing a complete subgraph with 5 vertices .

Tried to answer, but it confuses me that i have in graph one subgraph.
Thank you for the answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the vertices are labelled, otherwise the problem will be much harder.

- Choose $5$ of $10$ vertices to be the complete subgraph.... $C(10,5)$ ways.
- The total number of possible edges in a graph on $10$ vertices is $C(10,2)=45$.  Your complete subgraph accounts for $10$ edges, so you have to choose $5$ of the remaining $35$.... $C(35,5)$ ways.

Answer, $C(10,5)C(35,5)$.

Comment: I find solution in one book now, and u are correct. But i will kindly ask you if you can explain this solution more deeper, especialy second point. I have big exam tomorrow.. Thank you kind sir. This is a great community.

Comment: Which particular bit do you not understand?

Comment: "The total number of possible edges in a graph on 10 vertices is C(10,2)=45. Your complete subgraph accounts for 10 edges, so you have to choose 5 of the remaining 35...C(35,5) ways."

This part.

Comment: No. of possible edges = no. of pairs of vertices = $C(n,2)$.